# Why does SQL statement update more records than it needs to?

Tags: c#

I have problem with my code specifically on the update code.

```
private void updatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String Fname = fnametb.Text;
    String Lname = lnametb.Text;
    String Age = agetb.Text;
    String Address = addresstb.Text;
    String Course = coursetb.Text;

    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand();
        select.Connection = connection;
        select.CommandText = "Select * From Accounts";
        OleDbDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            OleDbCommand insert = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Accounts SET Firstname=@Fname, Lastname=@Lname, Age=@Age, Address=@Address, Course=@Course WHERE Lastname='"+ reader[2].ToString()+"'", connection);

            insert.Parameters.Add("@Fname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Fname;
            insert.Parameters.Add("@Lname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Lname;
            insert.Parameters.Add("@Age", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Age;
            insert.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Address;
            insert.Parameters.Add("@Course", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Course;
            insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

            fnametb.Clear();
            lnametb.Clear();
            agetb.Clear();
            addresstb.Clear();
            coursetb.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            searchtb.Clear();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

above is my code. Whenever I update one record, all the records in the table are affected.I think there's something wrong with the reader.
Please help, thanks.

Comment: Please choose a meaningful title for your question.

Comment: First problem: you've got a potential SQL injection attack. Use a parameter for the "where" part as well as for the new values. Also, given that it's an *update*, why are you calling it *insert*?

Comment: Debug your code and take a look what's in your where-statement. Execute your sql-statemend direct against your database

Comment: This code is _deliberately_ updating each account - for every row the `reader` finds, it's updating that row (and more, if there are duplicate last names).

Comment: offcourse it will update all records..
You are selecting all records in reader and iterating through...

Comment: it will update all the records as you select Statement is "Select * From Accounts";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are selecting all records,

```
select.CommandText = "Select * From Accounts";
```

then you loop the result with the reader.

```
while (reader.Read())
```

Then you update each record.

```
String sql = "UPDATE Accounts SET Firstname=@Fname, Lastname=@Lname, Age=@Age, Address=@Address, Course=@Course WHERE Lastname='"+ reader[2].ToString()+"'";
OleDbCommand insert = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
```

So why are you surprised?

I'm not sure what you actually want. Maybe you have forgotten to add a `WHERE` clause to your first select and you want to use `lnametb.Text`. But then the first select is simply redundant and you could use the `WHERE` for the update-command:

```
String sql = "UPDATE Accounts SET Firstname=@Fname, Lastname=@Lname, Age=@Age, Address=@Address, Course=@Course WHERE Lastname=@LastName";
insert.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lnametb.Text;
```

Btw, why have you named your update-command `insert`?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just overlooked the insert since I just copied my insert command then just change other variables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for some reason you execute the update in a loop for every record that the reader finds. Naturally, the reader would find every single last name that you have in the table, so the update is going to change every single record!

You need to remove the loop, remove the reader, and change the update command to use the last name from one of the entry boxes on the screen:

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand update = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Accounts SET Firstname=@Fname, Age=@Age, Address=@Address, Course=@Course WHERE Lastname=@Lname", connection);
update.Parameters.Add("@Fname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Fname;
update.Parameters.Add("@Lname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Lname;
update.Parameters.Add("@Age", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Age;
update.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Address;
update.Parameters.Add("@Course", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Course;
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Of course this does not let you update the last name: for that you need to supply some sort of an independent student ID, and use it in the `WHERE` clause of your `UPDATE` instead of the last name.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating all records from the table and setting to one value..
it is wrong access only the matching record and update it